# UITextfield check if its a number

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch

How can I check if a user enters a number in my `UITextField`. Basically its a mark I'm accepting between 0-100 and it can be a decimal. I heard that I can try to convert it to a `NSNumber` type and see if it returns null.

I have tried:

```
if(grade.text doubleValue] == 0){
   //Not a number
}
```

but then it still can accept "23f".

Answer (score 0):

Use NSScanner to detect whether a valid integer is in the string.

```
NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:myTextField.text];
NSInteger * integer;
if([scanner scanInteger:&integer]) {
  // valid number found
} else {
  // cry about it
}
```

You can improve on this by validating the text in the UITextField delegate method `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` to prevent the user from even entering an invalid value.

Comment: Using `scanDouble:` would have the same side-effect as `doubleValue` of allowing the 'f' character, since it indicates floating-point values in C.  What you can do instead is use the delegate method to prevent the user from entering the 'f'.

Comment: the Delegate Method does not seem to work, I have connected the controls Delegate

Comment: "does not seem to work" is too vague, we'll need more details.

Comment: `scanDouble:` is not "allowing" the 'f' character, it's just stopping the scan when it hits it. To verify that the field contains only the number, with no trailing garbage, you need to test `[scanner isAtEnd]` after `scanDouble:` returns successfully.

Comment: Also, think about using a numeric keyboard: `textField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good use case for NSRegularExpression.  I think this would work:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"[0-9\.]{1,2}|100" 
                  options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive 
                    error:&error];
NSUInteger matches = [regex numberOfMatchesInString:myTextField.text 
                                            options:0  
                                              range:NSMakeRange(0, [myTextField.text length])]
```

If matches equals 0 (no matches found), you don't have a number entered into the field.  This is just off the top of my head- I haven't tried it out yet.